# Legacy camera initialization after boot

Tags: camera, compute-module-4

I am in the situation where a camera hooked up to a CM4 is powered after booting has finished.

Is there a way to retrigger camera initialization through the legacy stack?

I tried to reload bcm2835-v4l2, but no /dev/video0 is created.